# How to convert multiple yaml files to single monolithic yaml file?

Tags: rest, yaml, swagger-2.0, openapi

I have a bunch of yaml files (one object definition goes into one yaml file) which need to be converted into one single yaml file (without any loss or add of any info).

The smaller yaml files are complete/holistic with all info the object needs.

Object_A.yaml >> Similarly object B, C etc

```
#Object A: REST API definitions
..
#Object A: Object definitions
...
#Object A: Response definitions
...
#Object A: Error definitions
.. etc
```

Monolithic_single_large_file.yaml

```
#Object A, B, C .. : REST API definitions
..
#Object A, B, C .. : Object definitions
...
#Object A, B, C .. : Response definitions
...
#Object A, B, C .. : Error definitions
.. etc
```

PS: Ideally the tool should take a directory (with the yaml files) or take multiple yaml files as input and generate a new yaml file with above conditions.

Comment: You already outlined how to do it yourself. Did you try to code it? Just load every object's yaml file into the same dictionary with a key of the object's name, and then output the dictionary to a new yaml file.

Comment: I dint try to code it myself thinking if there would be any known tool for the same. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following:

1. From https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-yaml-cli installed the merge-yaml tool to merge the different files (note: this merged all files but still had references to external files)
2. Then per my needs used 'sed' to sort issues with references to external file replacing and other issues

Comment: this tool seems to miss merges of "paths" section. Did you see that as a problem as well?